# uwsgi processes wont restart by

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

my setup is django1.8 + uwsgi2.0.11.1 + nginx with next build-options:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.8.0
built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/opt/nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-cc-opt=-Wno-error --with-pcre=/home/username/sources/pcre-8.37 --with-pcre --with-http_gzip_static_module --add-module=/home/username/sources/ngx_devel_kit-0.2.19 --add-module=/home/username/sources/set-misc-nginx-module-0.29
```

and uwsgi config:

```
[uwsgi]

chdir           = /home/aviasales/jr-content
wsgi-file       = lib/nginx/wsgi.py
touch-reload    = lib/nginx/touch_for_uwsgi_reload
home            = /home/aviasales/Envs/jetradar
daemonize       = /home/aviasales/jr-content/logs/uwsgi.log
stats           = 0.0.0.0:1717
die-on-term

master          = true
processes       = 10
socket          = /home/aviasales/jr-content/lib/nginx/unix.sock

chmod-socket    = 664
max-requests    = 5000

vacuum          = true

# NewRelic requirements
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true
```

the problem in that in `uwsgitop` I see the next:
[image]

uwsgi processes do not restart after 5000 requests:(

Comment: How does that screenshot show that they have not restarted after 5000?

Comment: @DanielRoseman the REQ column is requests amount